# How can I run user aliases with sudo?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I would like to be able to run the aliased commands I have defined for my current user in conjunction with `sudo` as well.

This does not work by default, because they would have to be defined for root instead of my current user in order to work with `sudo`.

An example is the `ll` alias:

```
$ type ll
ll is aliased to `ls -alF'
$ sudo ll /
sudo: ll: command not found
```

A special problem would be nested aliases:

```
bytecommander@BC-AlkaliMetal:~$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
```

So actually `ll` should evaluate to `ls -alf --color=auto`.

How can I run aliases defined for my current user as root with `sudo` properly?

Comment: Wouldn’t https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ be a better place for such a question?

Comment: Now that you mention it, maybe. But Bash and sudo are so strongly related to Ubuntu, therefore I'd guess it's also okay here.

Comment: I converted this question into a Q&A and posted the original version asking to proof-read my function [here on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/142574/63686).